# Log connections to SymmetricDS

Tags: java, tomcat, symmetricds

I have the following setup:

`server` and `client` nodes are deployed to Tomcat with `item` channel set to 0 on client. Everytime user presses a button that channel is set to 1, I wait till it synchronizes all and then set it to 0 again. I need to create a page on `server`, that would contain a table with rows | `client` | `time he last connected (pressed a button)` |. I want to know, is there a way to do that using SymmetricDS ways, like heartbeats?

I realized, that if I started/stopped client node instead of setting channels to 0, I could've just added these to `.properties` file:

```
start.heartbeat.job=false
heartbeat.sync.on.startup=true
```

and then just query `sym_data` table, but starting a node is long, and time is of the essense.

Any suggestions?

Comment: i haven't understood what you are trying to achieve. it seems like fighting with the tool instead of letting it do the job for you

Comment: I think I've already told you in one of my previous questions (maybe not) -- we're doing this for a client who's internet connection is very limited, so he will sync only when he has internet, so he has to press a button that will do this until fully synced, so he will be sure that he's up to date before leaving zone with the internet

Comment: No need to do anything but to monitor `sym_outgoing-batch` and `sym_incoming_batch` on a client. Once all batches are in status `OK` internet connection can be shut down.

Comment: Yeah, I've already figured out how to do that. Now I have to be able to get the list of such connection on server side. My solution so far is to write directly to `connection_history` table on server from client application

Comment: Go to the `sym_node` for a list of all registered clients.